# DataSet - Could not get type information for [app].[dataset]

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I recently started work with VS2013 and I need to create a report in a project.

**This is what I'm doing:**

1 - Right click on project -> Add -> New Item... -> Report (or Report Wizard);

2 - Add a dataset: create a data source from database (the connection is working fine, I can see my tables and columns);

3 - Select some tables and columns for my dataset (none of them has reserve words like 'system');

4 - Get the error `Could not get type information for [app].[dataset]`.

**I already tried:**

1 - delete my settings (connection) and recreate

2 - closed VS2013 and reopened

Nothing works, every time the same error.
Does anyone has a clue, please?
Thanks

=======================================

**I forgot to mention** that I already did this once. I was trying to add a data set to test, I did it, so I decided to delete and do it again. Since that I never was able to do it again.

Comment: maybe you have one of reserved keywords in your database schema?

Comment: I doubt, it is sadly all in portuguese

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred may be because you used Reserved field names such as "Name","System" and etc. in your database.